# Parsing datepicker date in javascript "dd monthstring, yyyy"

Tags: javascript, php, parsing, date, datetime

Is there an easier way of getting a datetime from a string such as this: "29 March, 2014" in **JAVASCRIPT**

I've done it within PHP, but I want to fiddle with some front end to add days to the date etc..

Here is the required PHP code to achieve this:

```
function removeDateComma($string){
    $without_comma = preg_replace('/,/', '', $string);
    return $without_comma;
}

function getYearMonthDayFromDate($string){
    $array  = array();
    $string = removeDateComma($string);
    $string = strtotime($string);
    $year   = date('Y', $string);  
    $month  = date('m', strtotime("-1 month", $string));  
    $day    = date('d', $string);
    $array['year'] = $year;
    $array['month'] = $month;
    $array['day'] = $day; 
    return $array;
}
```

Calling this to get the required datetime:

```
$from = getYearMonthDayFromDate($_REQUEST['from_date']);
```

**Can anyone come up with a solution to this problem? Getting the same result but in javascript?**

Edit:

It's already implemented in PHP. I need to do it at the front end i.e. no form submission, I cant send anything anywhere, i've got to get this date from an input field, i.e. `var field = document.getElementById("input_from").value;` so that will be in the format **11 Month, 2014**. So i've got this string sitting here which is useless, I need to get each individual value, i.e. the **year: 2014**, **month: 03 or 3** and **day: 11**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 function getMonthName( monthNumber ) 
    {
        var monthNames = new Array("January", "February", "March", 
      "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", 
      "October", "November", "December");
      return monthNames[monthNumber ]; 
    }
    var field = $("#input_from").val();

     var date1 = new Date(field); 
        var cMonth = date1.getMonth();
        var newdate = getMonthName(cMonth)   + " "+ date1.getDate() + ", " + date1.getFullYear();
alert(newdate);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chetangawai/MNbjw/

Comment: That looks more like it! I'll have a crack now :)

Comment: Yes this works perfectly, thank you for your time! reputation++ :D

Answer (score 0):

easy solution

```
 $date = date('Y-m-d' , strtotime('"29 March, 2014"'));
```

or add 2 days to it

```
 $date = date('Y-m-d' , strtotime('+2 days' , strtotime('"29 March, 2014"')));
```

Comment: in javascript, so i'd have to get the field contents then run a function on the value

Comment: this is php, just send the value over and handle with php

Comment: how about using `Date()` function of javascript??

Comment: yes, thats what i'm using, but I cant seem to find a solution to this particular problem

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: INPUT = 24 MARCH, 2014, I need to parse this in javascript, I would like the OUTPUT = {day = 24, month = 3, year = 2014}

Comment: dates function `toDateString()` is your easiest bet, but I don't think supports formatting.http://jsfiddle.net/tinybyte/njm4W/